# Adding a hyperlink to a userinterfaceonly protected sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

This is just to share knowledge. I couldn't find this particular case here.

Case: I protected a worksheet with `userinterfaceonly`, like this:

```
shLog.Protect Password:="foo", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
```

and then I tried to add some hyperlinks to the sheet, with

```
shLog.Hyperlinks.Add ...
```

expecting to be able to do that without unprotecting the sheet. However, I got error 1004 "*The cell or chart you're trying to change is on a protected sheet. ...*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in Excel 2016 (and maybe other versions). There are other posts referring to things you cannot do from VBA, even with `UserInterfaceOnly:=True`. The creating of hyperlinks with `.Hyperlinks.Add` can be added to that list. You have to turn off protection before adding the hyperlinks and turn it on again afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

To add on this answer, I found that setting the `AllowInsertingHyperlinks:=True` property while protecting the sheet allow adding hyperlink without removing protection.